# Mechanics of Peregrine Falcon Dive Pull Up

Tags: ornithology, bio-mechanics

There are loads of information on how fast the Peregrine Falcon dives, but aside from having specialized lungs, eyes, etc... to survive the dive.

What mechanics does it use to pull out of such a dive, specifically after it has hit it's prey.

My take is that it uses its [momentum to loop back in a U-shape](http://blogs.bu.edu/biolocomotion/2011/10/07/the-fastest-animal-on-earth-the-peregrine-falcon/), understand that by changing the angle of attack, this [generates the necessary drag & lift](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/jexbio/201/3/403.full.pdf) to pull out of the dive saftely.

My question is how effective is this & can a larger bird pull this off assuming it has all of said mechanics?